# What is the need for Memento Design Pattern in Calculator undo scenario

Tags: java, design-patterns, undo, memento

I am reading about Memento design pattern. I came across an example which talks about Calculator undo functionality.

I am able to achieve the Calculator Undo with the below code:

`Calculator`

```
public class Calculator implements Cloneable {

int num1;
int num2;
int result;

Stack<Calculator> states = new Stack<>();

public void setNum1(int num1) {
    this.num1 = num1;
}

public void setNum2(int num2) {
    this.num2 = num2;
}

public void setResult(int result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public int add() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    result = num1 + num2;
    states.add((Calculator) this.clone());
    System.out.println("Caclulation done. ");
    return result;
}

public void undo(){
    states.pop();
    Calculator calc = states.peek();
    this.setNum1(calc.num1);
    this.setNum2(calc.num2);
    this.setResult(calc.result);
    System.out.println("Undo done. ");
}

public void displayState(){
    System.out.println("Current State: " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + result);
}
}
```

`CalculatorTest`

```
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();

    calc.setNum1(10);
    calc.setNum2(11);
    calc.add();
    calc.displayState();

    calc.setNum1(12);
    calc.setNum2(13);
    calc.add();
    calc.displayState();

    calc.setNum1(16);
    calc.setNum2(17);
    calc.add();
    calc.displayState();

    calc.undo();
    calc.displayState();

    calc.undo();
    calc.displayState();
```

`Output`

> ```
> Caclulation done. 
> Current State: 10 + 11 = 21
> Caclulation done. 
> Current State: 12 + 13 = 25
> Caclulation done. 
> Current State: 16 + 17 = 33
> Undo done. 
> Current State: 12 + 13 = 25
> Undo done. 
> Current State: 10 + 11 = 21
> ```

It works well for the undo. Why would I use Memento pattern for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Source [Memento Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html)

> **Motivation**
>
> It is sometimes necessary to capture the internal state of an object
>   at some point and have the ability to restore the object to that state
>   later in time. Such a case is useful in case of error or failure.
>
> Consider the case of a calculator object with an undo operation such a
>   calculator could simply maintain a list of all previous operation that
>   it has performed and thus would be able to restore a previous
>   calculation it has performed. This would cause the calculator object
>   to become larger, more complex, and heavyweight, as the calculator
>   object would have to provide additional undo functionality and should
>   maintain a list of all previous operations.
>
> This functionality can be moved out of the calculator class, so that
>   an external (let's call it undo manager class) can collect the
>   internal state of the calculator and save it. However providing the
>   explicit access to every state variable of the calculator to the
>   restore manager would be impractical and would violate the
>   encapsulation principle.

Comment: So, *The calculator object will get bigger in size* and *Calculator will not adhere to SRP*..Are these the two design flaws that will be avoided if I use Memento pattern ?